# Ionic 4 Hide Toolbar on scroll

Tags: ionic-framework, ionic4

I'm trying to implement a directive to hide the Toolbar while scrolling.
I tried using this tutorial:
https://medium.com/@gregor.srdic/ionic3-hidding-header-on-footer-on-content-scroll-15ab95b05dc5

This worked with Ionic 3, but doesn't work with Ionic 4.

On the following code I get the error:

```
private adjustElementOnScroll(ev) {
    if (ev) {
        console.log(ev);
        ev.domWrite(() => {
            let scrollTop: number = ev.scrollTop > 0 ? ev.scrollTop : 0;
            let scrolldiff: number = scrollTop - this.lastScrollPosition;
            this.lastScrollPosition = scrollTop;
            let newValue = this.lastValue + scrolldiff;
            newValue = Math.max(0, Math.min(newValue, this.config.maxValue));
            this.renderer.setStyle(this.element.nativeElement, this.config.cssProperty, `-${newValue}px`);
            this.lastValue = newValue;
        });
    }
}
```

Error:

```
ev.domWrite is not a function
```

I checked, and `ev` in Ionic 4 is a `CustomEvent`, not a `ScrollEvent`.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Above solutions no longer works. Ionic 4 beta APIs has changed a lot in recent months.

#### you have to import `IonContent` instead of `Content`.

```
//scroll-hide.directive.ts
import { IonContent, DomController } from '@ionic/angular';
import { Directive, ElementRef, Input, Renderer2, SimpleChanges } from '@angular/core';
```

#### import the directive where you want to use it, instead of `app.module.ts`

for example in relevant module,

```
//ex: home.module.ts
import { ScrollHideDirective } from '../../directives/scroll-hide.directive';

@NgModule({
    ...
  declarations: [...,ScrollHideDirective],
    ...
})


then in the ts file,


//ex: home.page.ts
import { ScrollHideConfig } from '../../directives/scroll-hide.directive';


export class HomePage implements OnInit {

...
    footerScrollConfig: ScrollHideConfig = { cssProperty: 'margin-bottom', maxValue: undefined };
    headerScrollConfig: ScrollHideConfig = { cssProperty: 'margin-top', maxValue: 54 };
...

}
```

reversed version of directive

```
//ex: scroll-hide.directive.ts    

import { IonContent, DomController } from '@ionic/angular';
import { Directive, ElementRef, Input, Renderer2, SimpleChanges } from '@angular/core';

    @Directive({
      selector: '[scrollHide]'
      })
export class ScrollHideDirective {

  @Input('scrollHide') config: ScrollHideConfig;
  @Input('scrollContent') scrollContent: IonContent;

  contentHeight: number;
  scrollHeight: number;
  lastScrollPosition: number;
  lastValue: number = 0;

  constructor(private element: ElementRef, private renderer: Renderer2, private  domCtrl: DomController) {
  }

  ngOnChanges(changes: SimpleChanges) {
    if(this.scrollContent && this.config) {
      this.scrollContent.scrollEvents = true;

      let scrollStartFunc = async (ev) => {
        const el = await this.scrollContent.getScrollElement();
        this.contentHeight = el.offsetHeight;
        this.scrollHeight = el.scrollHeight;
        if (this.config.maxValue === undefined) {
          this.config.maxValue = this.element.nativeElement.offsetHeight;
        }
        this.lastScrollPosition = el.scrollTop;
      };

      if(this.scrollContent && this.scrollContent instanceof IonContent) {
        this.scrollContent.ionScrollStart.subscribe(scrollStartFunc);
        this.scrollContent.ionScroll.subscribe(async (ev) => this.adjustElementOnScroll(ev));
        this.scrollContent.ionScrollEnd.subscribe(async (ev) => this.adjustElementOnScroll(ev));

      } else if(this.scrollContent instanceof HTMLElement) {
        (this.scrollContent as HTMLElement).addEventListener('ionScrollStart', scrollStartFunc);
        (this.scrollContent as HTMLElement).addEventListener('ionScroll',async (ev) => this.adjustElementOnScroll(ev));
        (this.scrollContent as HTMLElement).addEventListener('ionScrollEnd',async (ev) => this.adjustElementOnScroll(ev));
      }
    }
  }

  private adjustElementOnScroll(ev) {
    if (ev) {
      this.domCtrl.write(async () => {
        const el = await this.scrollContent.getScrollElement();
        let scrollTop: number = el.scrollTop > 0 ? el.scrollTop : 0;
        let scrolldiff: number = scrollTop - this.lastScrollPosition;
        this.lastScrollPosition = scrollTop;
        let newValue = this.lastValue + scrolldiff;
        newValue = Math.max(0, Math.min(newValue, this.config.maxValue));
        this.renderer.setStyle(this.element.nativeElement, this.config.cssProperty, `-${newValue}px`);
        this.lastValue = newValue;
      });
    }
  }
}

export interface ScrollHideConfig {
  cssProperty: string;
  maxValue: number;
}
```

the html ex: page.html (No Change)

```
<ion-header [scrollHide]="headerScrollConfig" [scrollContent]="pageContent">
  ...
</ion-header>

<ion-content #pageContent fullscreen>
  ...
</ion-content>

<ion-footer [scrollHide]="footerScrollConfig" [scrollContent]="pageContent">
...
</ion-footer>
```

hope it helps.

Comment: any idea how to use it with ion tabs?

Comment: do you want to hide the tabs? anyway, you can apply the same principle.

Comment: I am unable to do so as, tabs page has no content or ion-content tag
Have a look at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54307676/ionic-4-hide-ion-tab-bar-while-scrolling-just-like-linkedin-app

Comment: I see you got a issue with the filkering thing, lets play around with 

```footerScrollConfig: ScrollHideConfig = { cssProperty: 'margin-bottom', maxValue: undefined };
 ` headerScrollConfig: ScrollHideConfig = { cssProperty: 'margin-top', maxValue: 54 };```

these two max values. I am using it with the tabs. It works fine.

Comment: Thank you for this.

Comment: Gald I could help. 

Answer (score 6):

**Modified directive for Ionic 4.**

```js
import { Content, DomController } from '@ionic/angular';
import { Directive, ElementRef, Input, Renderer2, SimpleChanges } from '@angular/core';

@Directive({
    selector: '[scrollHide]'
})
export class ScrollHideDirective {

    @Input('scrollHide') config: ScrollHideConfig;
    @Input('scrollContent') scrollContent: Content;

    contentHeight: number;
    scrollHeight: number;
    lastScrollPosition: number;
    lastValue: number = 0;

    constructor(private element: ElementRef, private renderer: Renderer2, private domCtrl: DomController) {
    }

    ngOnChanges(changes: SimpleChanges) {
        if (this.scrollContent && this.config) {
            this.scrollContent.ionScrollStart.subscribe(async (ev) => {
                const el = await this.scrollContent.getScrollElement();
                this.contentHeight = el.offsetHeight;
                this.scrollHeight = el.scrollHeight;    
                if (this.config.maxValue === undefined) {
                    this.config.maxValue = this.element.nativeElement.offsetHeight;
                }
                this.lastScrollPosition = el.scrollTop;
            });
            this.scrollContent.ionScroll.subscribe((ev) => this.adjustElementOnScroll(ev));
            this.scrollContent.ionScrollEnd.subscribe((ev) => this.adjustElementOnScroll(ev));
        }
    }

    private adjustElementOnScroll(ev) {
        if (ev) {
            this.domCtrl.write(async () => {
                const el = await this.scrollContent.getScrollElement();
                let scrollTop: number = el.scrollTop > 0 ? el.scrollTop : 0;
                let scrolldiff: number = scrollTop - this.lastScrollPosition;
                this.lastScrollPosition = scrollTop;
                let newValue = this.lastValue + scrolldiff;
                newValue = Math.max(0, Math.min(newValue, this.config.maxValue));
                this.renderer.setStyle(this.element.nativeElement, this.config.cssProperty, `-${newValue}px`);
                this.lastValue = newValue;
            });
        }
    }
}
export interface ScrollHideConfig {
    cssProperty: string;
    maxValue: number;
}
```

Comment: thanks! show/hide is working! Just a little bit imperfect. The footer disappeared or displayed in a sudden, there's supposed to be some animation

Comment: To solve animation problems, you need to bind `[scrollEvents]` and set it to `true` on the main content like so `<ion-content #content fullscreen [scrollEvents]="true">`.

Answer (score 5):

The event may have changed in Ionic 4, but you can still import the `DomController` from `@ionic/angular`

```
import {..., DomController } from "@ionic/angular";
```

and inject it in the constructor

```
constructor(
    // ...
    private domCtrl: DomController
) { }
```

And then use the `write()` method like this:

```
private adjustElementOnScroll(ev) {
    if (ev) {
        this.domCtrl.write(() => {
            // ...
        });
    }
}
```

The `DomController` is just a way for Ionic to create a queue for callbacks that would write or read the DOM in order to use the `window.requestAnimationFrame()` method behind the scenes.

For more information, please visit:

1. **[`DomController` source code](https://github.com/ionic-team/ionic/blob/master/angular/src/providers/dom-controller.ts)**
2. **[`requestAnimationFrame` MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/window/requestAnimationFrame)**

Comment: any idea how to use it with ion tabs?

Answer (score 0):

The below code worked for me, with minor corrections from above code

```
import { Content, DomController } from '@ionic/angular';
import { Directive, ElementRef, Input, Renderer2, SimpleChanges } from '@angular/core';

@Directive({
  selector: '[scrollHide]'
  })
export class ScrollHideDirective {

  @Input('scrollHide') config: ScrollHideConfig;
  @Input('scrollContent') scrollContent: Content;

  contentHeight: number;
  scrollHeight: number;
  lastScrollPosition: number;
  lastValue: number = 0;

  constructor(private element: ElementRef, private renderer: Renderer2, private domCtrl: DomController) {
  }

  ngOnChanges(changes: SimpleChanges) {
    if(this.scrollContent && this.config) {
      this.scrollContent.scrollEvents = true;

      let scrollStartFunc = async (ev) => {
        const el = await this.scrollContent.getScrollElement();
        this.contentHeight = el.offsetHeight;
        this.scrollHeight = el.scrollHeight;
        if (this.config.maxValue === undefined) {
          this.config.maxValue = this.element.nativeElement.offsetHeight;
        }
        this.lastScrollPosition = el.scrollTop;
      };

      if(this.scrollContent && this.scrollContent instanceof Content) {
        this.scrollContent.ionScrollStart.subscribe(scrollStartFunc);
        this.scrollContent.ionScroll.subscribe(async (ev) => this.adjustElementOnScroll(ev));
        this.scrollContent.ionScrollEnd.subscribe(async (ev) => this.adjustElementOnScroll(ev));

      } else if(this.scrollContent instanceof HTMLElement) {
        (this.scrollContent as HTMLElement).addEventListener('ionScrollStart', scrollStartFunc);
        (this.scrollContent as HTMLElement).addEventListener('ionScroll',async (ev) => this.adjustElementOnScroll(ev));
        (this.scrollContent as HTMLElement).addEventListener('ionScrollEnd',async (ev) => this.adjustElementOnScroll(ev));
      }
    }
  }

  private adjustElementOnScroll(ev) {
    if (ev) {
      this.domCtrl.write(async () => {
        const el = await this.scrollContent.getScrollElement();
        let scrollTop: number = el.scrollTop > 0 ? el.scrollTop : 0;
        let scrolldiff: number = scrollTop - this.lastScrollPosition;
        this.lastScrollPosition = scrollTop;
        let newValue = this.lastValue + scrolldiff;
        newValue = Math.max(0, Math.min(newValue, this.config.maxValue));
        this.renderer.setStyle(this.element.nativeElement, this.config.cssProperty, `-${newValue}px`);
        this.lastValue = newValue;
      });
    }
  }
}
export interface ScrollHideConfig {
  cssProperty: string;
  maxValue: number;
}
```