# Ionic 4 : Hide ion-tab-bar while scrolling, just like LinkedIn app

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, ionic4

I am using default ion-tab-bar with bottom placement as shown in the LinkedIn app.
I want to hide the tab-bar while scrolling and show it again when scrolling stops. This feature can be seen in the LinkedIn app.

Here is tabs.page.html

```
<ion-tabs >

  <ion-tab-bar slot="bottom" >
    <ion-tab-button tab="tab1">
      <ion-icon name="desktop"></ion-icon>
      <ion-label>Tab Three</ion-label>
    </ion-tab-button>

    <ion-tab-button tab="tab2">
      <ion-icon name="person"></ion-icon>
      <ion-label>Tab Two</ion-label>
    </ion-tab-button>

    <ion-tab-button tab="tab3">
      <ion-icon name="send"></ion-icon>
      <ion-label>Tab Three</ion-label>
    </ion-tab-button>
  </ion-tab-bar>

</ion-tabs>
```

Answer (score 4):

Add this to the `tab.page.ts`

```
  ngOnInit() {
    let content = document.querySelector('ion-content');
    content.scrollEvents = true;
    content.addEventListener('ionScrollStart', () => {
          document.querySelector('ion-tab-bar').style.display = 'none';
    });
    content.addEventListener('ionScrollEnd', () => {
          document.querySelector('ion-tab-bar').style.display = 'flex';
    });
   }
```

This will do the trick...

Comment: Yes, it works but has a bug, when the scroll is in the mid-screen, the screen starts to scroll up and down a bit automatically so it looks flickering.

Comment: Possible, this is the main approach, I suggest to you play around a bit ex : add `fadein` `fadeout` maybe some `settimeout` for little delay etc. based on your app. Its hard to assume what really happens there.